# Testing a knockout javascript page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jasmine

I have Jasmine, Knockout, and jQuery on a webpage.  I had written some tests that I thought would verify that the view model is bound to the DOM the way I expect, but jQuery doesn't seem to be able to simulate user interaction the way I thought it would:

e.g.

```html
<input type='text' id='someField' data-bind='value: someField'>

<script>

  var viewModel = { someField: ko.observable() };

  // ...

  //this test passes
  it('should update the DOM when I edit the model', function(){

      $('#someField').val('not the test value');

      viewModel.someField('test value');

      expect( $('#someField').val() ).toBe('test value');
  });

  //this test does not
  it('should update the model when I change the DOM', function(){

      viewModel.someField('not the test value');

      $('#someField').val('test value');

      expect( viewModel.someField() ).toBe('test value');
  });

</script>
```

The first test passes, and the second test fails.  When I actually edit someField manually, the view model does change though; only the test fails, not the behaviour it is testing.  When editing the page manually, the view model update seems to happen 'onblur', so I changed the relevant line in the test to:

```
$('#someField').val('test value').next('input').focus();
```

but it still fails.

I have similar tests for radio buttons.  When I click them manually, the view model does change, but in a test, calling `$('#radioButton').click();` does not update the view model.

Why is Knockout not recognizing jQuery's changes to the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call .change() to have knockout pick up that the value has been changed programatically.

```
$('#someField').val('test value').change();
```

**For this to work jQuery MUST be included/loaded before knockout!**

This probably has something to do with that fact that Knockout.js will use jQuery's abstraction for event handling if jQuery is present, if not it will use the DOM Event API directly.  https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js (registerEventHandler and triggerEvent)

This should probably be fixed in Knockout.js.

Comment: That sounds right, but I just tried it and nothing happened.  (I suspect that my attempt at focusing another element was a clumsy way of doing exactly what you suggested -- your way is more correct, but not extremely different.)  Maybe there is some other event that knockout is waiting for?

Comment: Actually, 'change' on text inputs is deferred until it loses focus anyway.  Still, even combining the whole thing:  `$('#someField').val('test value').change().blur();` doesn't change the test ... it still fails.

Comment: I forgot you also need to give knockout some time do it's magic before expecting on the observable.

Comment: Note that when using jasmine async features you (probably) need to wrap all your test code in "runs" and "waitsFor"

Comment: Yep, changed it to use runs/waitsFor, still fails.  After 5000 milliseconds, viewModel.someField is still 'not the test value'.  (Thanks for the suggestions.)

Comment: Tried on jsfiddle, and it seems the solution is that you absolutly MUST include jQuery before Knockout.js for .change to work. Luckily you don't need to care about jasmine async after all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43683/discussion-between-brad-and-hallvar-helleseth)